# Program that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: python

I'm working on a program which calls a function to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit. I've successfully got the program working as to how it should be I'm trying to make some other improvements and am stuck on how I can make it so if the user entered in '20.5' it would display the answer in the console successfully without an error.

However, I'm only trying to only include a certain range for example from 20 - 30. So this would include 20.5, 21, 21,5, 22, 22.5 etc.

I've been looking online for solutions on how to do so but can't seem to find anything. Any help or tips would be highly appreciated!

Below is my current code working:
(Ignore Docstring)

```
Tc = int(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))
Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32
def convert(Tc, Tf):
    """'convert' function takes 2 parameters, 'Tc' & 'Tf' and 
        completes the operation for the two variables"""
    print(Tc, "in degrees Celsius is", Tf, "in degrees Fahrenheit")
    return Tf
convert(Tc, Tf)
```

Comment: Remove that int from first line.

Comment: Welcome to Python. I think you need to back up and learn a little bit more about programming in general. What is the purpose of your `convert` function? Right now, all of the logic that actually does the conversion is in the line `Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32` which is *outside* the function! On the other hand, the `print` statement has *nothing* to do with the conversion, and so probably belongs elsewhere!

Comment: Literally, your `convert()` just prints out output. Shouldn't you switch to actual conversion within the function?

Comment: Use those answers and then make if Tc < 30 and Tc > 20:

Comment: @N00b It should infact be something like: `if Tc <= 20 or Tc >= 30`

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` instead of `int`:

**Instead of**:

```
Tc = int(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))
```

**Use**:

```
Tc = float(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))
```

**Why**:

If the user-input data is converted to `int`, you will get the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.5'

On the other hand, if you convert it to `float` it would work fine for both `int` and `float` values.

Also, the Calculation/Conversion should be done inside the function, not outside.

**OP**:  *I'm only trying to only include a certain range for example from 20 - 30*

You could use a check like: `if Tc <= 20 or Tc >= 30:` inside the function and it fails, `exit()`.

**Hence**:

```
Tc = float(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))

def convert(Tc):
    """'convert' function takes 2 parameters, 'Tc' & 'Tf' and
        completes the operation for the two variables"""
    if Tc <= 20 or Tc >= 30:
        Tf = ((9 * Tc) / 5) + 32
        print(Tc, "in degrees Celsius is", Tf, "in degrees Fahrenheit")
    else:
        print("Invalid Temperature")
        exit()
    return Tf

convert(Tc)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter a Temperature in Celsius: 20.5
20.5 in degrees Celsius is 68.9 in degrees Fahrenheit
```

**Range Check**:

```
Enter a Temperature in Celsius: 31
Invalid Temperature
```

Answer (score 0):

Read and convert as `float` like this with `float(input())`

```
Tc = float(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))
Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32
def convert(Tc, Tf):
    """'convert' function takes 1 parameter, 'Tc' - temperature in celcius
        and converts it to faranheit"""
    print(Tc, "in degrees Celsius is", Tf, "in degrees Fahrenheit")
    return Tf
convert(Tc, Tf)

# Output

Enter a Temperature in Celsius: 26.35
26.35 in degrees Celsius is 79.43 in degrees Fahrenheit
```

Apart from this, there is something that I noticed in your code where you compute the result outside the function ie `Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32`

You can include that line inside the function and show the result. Which is the ideal way to use a function.

You can do like this

```
def convert(Tc):
    """'convert' function takes 2 parameters, 'Tc' & 'Tf' and 
        completes the operation for the two variables"""

    Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32


    print(Tc, "in degrees Celsius is", Tf, "in degrees Fahrenheit")
    return Tf

Tc = float(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))

convert(Tc)
```

Here you are reading input and then passing it to the function where the function computes the result and returns back the result. This is the ideal method to use functions in your code.

In your question you mentioned

> However, I'm only trying to only include a certain range for example from 20 - 30. So this would include 20.5, 21, 21,5, 22, 22.5 etc.

So you want only to do the conversion in this range, else just display some other message. You can do a simple check in the function with a simple `if`.

Also, this code can be made better and efficient if you could separate computing and displaying in two different functions. Which is the best practice

```
def display_temp(Tc, Tf):

    '''
        function to display temperature in farenheit

    '''

    print(Tc, "in degrees Celsius is", Tf, "in degrees Fahrenheit")



def convert(Tc):

    """ convert function takes 1 parameter, 'Tc' - Temperature in celcius and 
        converts it to farenheit if Tc falls in range 20 - 30"""


    if Tc <= 20 or Tc >= 30:
        print('Invalid Temperature -- Out of range [20, 30]')
        return -1

    Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32

    display_temp(Tc, Tf)

    return Tf

Tc = float(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))

convert(Tc)
```

Now the function shows an error message and returns -1 when the temperature is not in range.

Comment: Even better advice would be to also separate conversion and printing.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called 'convert', but all it actually does is print a line.

All you need is

```
Tc = float(input("Enter a Temperature in Celsius: "))
Tf = ((9 * Tc)/5) + 32
print(Tc, "in degrees Celsius is", Tf, "in degrees Fahrenheit")
```

The reason you were getting an error, is because you were entering 20.5, and then forcing it to be an int. Just change the 'int' to 'float' and the problem is solved.